# The missing records of Kafka consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

There is an problem between Kafka and Spark-Streaming, I have a low-level traffic (around 12000 - 15000 records / per second) services in production, at first, the consuming traffic seems normal, but after 10 - 15 mins, suddenly the speed of consuming almost 1/10 left. It might be network's traffic problem?

**Configurations of Kafka:**
    num.network.threads=2
    num.io.threads=8
    socket.send.buffer.bytes=1048576
    socket.receive.buffer.bytes=1048576
    socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
    log.flush.interval.messages=10000
    log.flush.interval.ms=1000
    log.retention.hours=12
    log.segment.bytes=536870912
    log.retention.check.interval.ms=60000
    log.cleaner.enable=false
    log.cleanup.interval.mins=1

**Configurations of spark-streaming (consumer):**

```
....
val kafkaParams = Map(
    "zookeeper.connect" -> zkQuorum,
    "group.id" -> group,
    "zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms" -> "1000000",
    "zookeeper.sync.time.ms" -> "200",
    "fetch.message.max.bytes" -> "2097152000",
    "queued.max.message.chunks" -> "1000",
    "auto.commit.enable" -> "true",
    "auto.commit.interval.ms" -> "1000")

try {
    KafkaUtils.createStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](
      ssc, kafkaParams, topics.map((_, partition)).toMap,
      StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY).map {
      case (key, value) => convertTo(key, value)
    }.filter {
      _ != null
    }.foreachRDD(line => saveToHBase(line, INPUT_TABLE))
    //}.foreachRDD(line => logger.info("handling testing....."+ line))
  } catch {
    case e: Exception => logger.error("consumerEx: " + e.printStackTrace)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be GC pause time, maybe. Check this: http://ingest.tips/2015/01/21/handling-large-messages-kafka/